# How to change Fingerprint in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I use python selenium.
I have a json file with this such fingerprint:

```
{"valid":true,"plugins":[{"ref":1446158656,"description":"Portable Document Format","filename":"internal-pdf-viewer","name":"PDF Viewer","mimes":[-1248334925,-1004735216]},{"ref":1010824838,"description":"Portable Document Format","filename":"internal-pdf-viewer","name":"Chrome PDF Viewer","mimes":[-1248334925,-1004735216]},{"ref":-1972253206,"description":"Portable Document Format","filename":"internal-pdf-viewer","name":"Chromium PDF Viewer","mimes":[-1248334925,-1004735216]},{"ref":-545395695,"description":"Portable Document Format","filename":"internal-pdf-viewer","name":"Microsoft Edge PDF Viewer","mimes":[-1248334925,-1004735216]},{"ref":1114102244,"description":"Portable Document Format","filename":"internal-pdf-viewer","name":"WebKit built-in PDF","mimes":[-1248334925,-1004735216]}],"mimes":[{"ref":-1248334925,"description":"Portable Document Format","suffixes":"pdf","type":"application/pdf","plugin":1446158656},{"ref":-1004735216,"description":"Portable Document Format","suffixes":"pdf","type":"text/pdf","plugin":1446158656}],"ua":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/105.0.1343.42","tags":["Microsoft Windows","Chrome","Desktop","Windows 10"],"dnt":false,"width":1553,"height":749,"canvas":"40f509adc22f058c83898e21b6aec78772e7151591b9c93e2fee5e1180d376884de77289249b27f0f74abb765b8992bca96f28b29bb02c7a309fa718357d3e0d7f83837f837b7c7b7f7e817f7b7b7b7f827c827f827e7b7b7e7c7c7e7e7f7d817b7b81807f80827c7f7b7e837e7e838182827d","webgl":"d3ac117c2e17e9bb6723d9b9676db7d5b9b30cdea3490ae18bc00c49dc04f5015ea71a57b75f4e78048e072f5f107e5e4bfc394c4bf21807b36cfa417deec8067f83837f837b7c7b7f7e817f7b7b7b7f827c827f827e7b7b7e7c7c7e7e7f7d817b7b81807f80827c7f7b7e837e7e838182827d","rectangles":"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","audio":"f89e8f36583094aecdc796a9768960336dfb6ff317c44bd3f451bc9e7a06419f401a175af59c4c243f891e2d8e4251656e9547194e1c5d85269bb67c46fece04927f8d6d937c6e74828390827e867480836e6b8f8782727873758a8f90848c7e738079937085818a80917a8090786d8c7f6b876f8f7a72798b788b7c7382938593866b856e92926c70898b90868687817f8092918c8b7d91887190718a70818282807286","battery":"aa807911c85f1ba1e96a7060b553c52c356c8308d50a2947918379a376c1bd3a6b47944e4820b463abd7b66f8edd8cfd9b3ce8d91d972c305a0be3e4fa9b940009995a21310d51","has_battery_api":true,"has_battery_device":false,"webgl_properties":{"unmaskedVendor":"Google Inc. (NVIDIA)","unmaskedRenderer":"ANGLE (NVIDIA, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070 Direct3D11 vs_5_0 ps_5_0, D3D11)","vendor":"WebKit","renderer":"WebKit WebGL","shadingLanguage":"WebGL GLSL ES 1.0 (OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0 Chromium)","version":"WebGL 1.0 (OpenGL ES 2.0 Chromium)","maxAnisotropy":"16","shadingLanguage2":"WebGL GLSL ES 3.00 (OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.0 Chromium)","version2":"WebGL 2.0 (OpenGL ES 3.0 Chromium)","aliasedLineWidthRange":{"0":1,"1":1},"aliasedPointSizeRange":{"0":1,"1":1024},"alphaBits":"8","blueBits":"8","depthBits":"24","greenBits":"8","maxCombinedTextureImageUnits":"32","maxCubeMapTextureSize":"16384","maxFragmentUniformVectors":"1024","maxRenderBufferSize":"16384","maxTextureImageUnits":"16","maxTextureSize":"16384","maxVaryingVectors":"30","maxVertexAttribs":"16","maxVertexTextureImageUnits":"16","maxVertexUniformVectors":"4095","maxViewportDims":{"0":32767,"1":32767},"redBits":"8","stencilBits":"8","subpixelBits":"4","sampleBuffers":"1","samples":"4","stencilBackValueMask":"2147483647","stencilBackWritemask":"2147483647","stencilValueMask":"2147483647","stencilWritemask":"2147483647","maxColorAttachmentsWebgl":"8","maxDrawBuffersWebgl":"8","webglContextAttributesDefaults":{"alpha":true,"antialias":true,"depth":true,"desynchronized":false,"failIfMajorPerformanceCaveat":false,"powerPreference":"default","premultipliedAlpha":true,"preserveDrawingBuffer":false,"stencil":false,"xrCompatible":false},"extensions":"ANGLE_instanced_arrays,EXT_blend_minmax,EXT_color_buffer_half_float,EXT_disjoint_timer_query,EXT_float_blend,EXT_frag_depth,EXT_shader_texture_lod,EXT_texture_compression_bptc,EXT_texture_compression_rgtc,EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic,EXT_sRGB,KHR_parallel_shader_compile,OES_element_index_uint,OES_fbo_render_mipmap,OES_standard_derivatives,OES_texture_float,OES_texture_float_linear,OES_texture_half_float,OES_texture_half_float_linear,OES_vertex_array_object,WEBGL_color_buffer_float,WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc,WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc_srgb,WEBGL_debug_renderer_info,WEBGL_debug_shaders,WEBGL_depth_texture,WEBGL_draw_buffers,WEBGL_lose_context,WEBGL_multi_draw","precisionVertexShaderHighFloat":23,"rangeMinVertexShaderHighFloat":127,"rangeMaxVertexShaderHighFloat":127,"precisionVertexShaderMediumFloat":23,"rangeMinVertexShaderMediumFloat":127,"rangeMaxVertexShaderMediumFloat":127,"precisionVertexShaderLowFloat":23,"rangeMinVertexShaderLowFloat":127,"rangeMaxVertexShaderLowFloat":127,"precisionFragmentShaderHighFloat":23,"rangeMinFragmentShaderHighFloat":127,"rangeMaxFragmentShaderHighFloat":127,"precisionFragmentShaderMediumFloat":23,"rangeMinFragmentShaderMediumFloat":127,"rangeMaxFragmentShaderMediumFloat":127,"precisionFragmentShaderLowFloat":23,"rangeMinFragmentShaderLowFloat":127,"rangeMaxFragmentShaderLowFloat":127,"precisionVertexShaderHighInt":0,"rangeMinVertexShaderHighInt":31,"rangeMaxVertexShaderHighInt":30,"precisionVertexShaderMediumInt":0,"rangeMinVertexShaderMediumInt":31,"rangeMaxVertexShaderMediumInt":30,"precisionVertexShaderLowInt":0,"rangeMinVertexShaderLowInt":31,"rangeMaxVertexShaderLowInt":30,"precisionFragmentShaderHighInt":0,"rangeMinFragmentShaderHighInt":31,"rangeMaxFragmentShaderHighInt":30,"precisionFragmentShaderMediumInt":0,"rangeMinFragmentShaderMediumInt":31,"rangeMaxFragmentShaderMediumInt":30,"precisionFragmentShaderLowInt":0,"rangeMinFragmentShaderLowInt":31,"rangeMaxFragmentShaderLowInt":30,"maxVertexUniformComponents2":"16380","maxVertexUniformBlocks2":"12","maxVertexOutputComponents2":"120","maxVaryingComponents2":"120","maxTransformFeedbackInterleavedComponents2":"120","maxTransformFeedbackSeparateAttribs2":"4","maxTransformFeedbackSeparateComponents2":"4","maxFragmentUniformComponents2":"4096","maxFragmentUniformBlocks2":"12","maxFragmentInputComponents2":"120","minProgramTexelOffset2":"-8","maxProgramTexelOffset2":"7","maxDrawBuffers2":"8","maxColorAttachments2":"8","maxSamples2":"8","max3DTextureSize2":"2048","maxArrayTextureLayers2":"2048","maxClientWaitTimeoutWebgl2":"0","maxElementIndex2":"4294967294","maxServerWaitTimeout2":"0","stencilBackValueMask2":"2147483647","stencilBackWritemask2":"2147483647","stencilValueMask2":"2147483647","stencilWritemask2":"2147483647","maxTextureLodBias2":"2","maxUniformBufferBindings2":"24","maxUniformBlockSize2":"65536","uniformBufferOffsetAlignment2":"256","maxCombinedUniformBlocks2":"24","maxCombinedVertexUniformComponents2":"212988","maxCombinedFragmentUniformComponents2":"200704","maxElementsVertices2":"2147483647","maxElementsIndices2":"2147483647","aliasedLineWidthRange2":{"0":1,"1":1},"aliasedPointSizeRange2":{"0":1,"1":1024},"webglContextAttributesDefaults2":{"alpha":true,"antialias":true,"depth":true,"desynchronized":false,"failIfMajorPerformanceCaveat":false,"powerPreference":"default","premultipliedAlpha":true,"preserveDrawingBuffer":false,"stencil":false,"xrCompatible":false},"alphaBits2":"8","blueBits2":"8","depthBits2":"24","greenBits2":"8","maxCombinedTextureImageUnits2":"32","maxCubeMapTextureSize2":"16384","maxFragmentUniformVectors2":"1024","maxRenderBufferSize2":"16384","maxTextureImageUnits2":"16","maxTextureSize2":"16384","maxVaryingVectors2":"30","maxVertexAttribs2":"16","maxVertexTextureImageUnits2":"16","maxVertexUniformVectors2":"4095","maxViewportDims2":{"0":32767,"1":32767},"redBits2":"8","stencilBits2":"8","subpixelBits2":"4","sampleBuffers2":"1","samples2":"4","extensions2":"EXT_color_buffer_float,EXT_color_buffer_half_float,EXT_disjoint_timer_query_webgl2,EXT_float_blend,EXT_texture_compression_bptc,EXT_texture_compression_rgtc,EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic,EXT_texture_norm16,KHR_parallel_shader_compile,OES_draw_buffers_indexed,OES_texture_float_linear,WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc,WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc_srgb,WEBGL_debug_renderer_info,WEBGL_debug_shaders,WEBGL_lose_context,WEBGL_multi_draw,OVR_multiview2","precisionVertexShaderHighFloat2":23,"rangeMinVertexShaderHighFloat2":127,"rangeMaxVertexShaderHighFloat2":127,"precisionVertexShaderMediumFloat2":23,"rangeMinVertexShaderMediumFloat2":127,"rangeMaxVertexShaderMediumFloat2":127,"precisionVertexShaderLowFloat2":23,"rangeMinVertexShaderLowFloat2":127,"rangeMaxVertexShaderLowFloat2":127,"precisionFragmentShaderHighFloat2":23,"rangeMinFragmentShaderHighFloat2":127,"rangeMaxFragmentShaderHighFloat2":127,"precisionFragmentShaderMediumFloat2":23,"rangeMinFragmentShaderMediumFloat2":127,"rangeMaxFragmentShaderMediumFloat2":127,"precisionFragmentShaderLowFloat2":23,"rangeMinFragmentShaderLowFloat2":127,"rangeMaxFragmentShaderLowFloat2":127,"precisionVertexShaderHighInt2":0,"rangeMinVertexShaderHighInt2":31,"rangeMaxVertexShaderHighInt2":30,"precisionVertexShaderMediumInt2":0,"rangeMinVertexShaderMediumInt2":31,"rangeMaxVertexShaderMediumInt2":30,"precisionVertexShaderLowInt2":0,"rangeMinVertexShaderLowInt2":31,"rangeMaxVertexShaderLowInt2":30,"precisionFragmentShaderHighInt2":0,"rangeMinFragmentShaderHighInt2":31,"rangeMaxFragmentShaderHighInt2":30,"precisionFragmentShaderMediumInt2":0,"rangeMinFragmentShaderMediumInt2":31,"rangeMaxFragmentShaderMediumInt2":30,"precisionFragmentShaderLowInt2":0,"rangeMinFragmentShaderLowInt2":31,"rangeMaxFragmentShaderLowInt2":30},"audio_properties":{"BaseAudioContextSampleRate":48000,"AudioContextBaseLatency":0.01,"AudioContextOutputLatency":0,"AudioDestinationNodeMaxChannelCount":2,"AnalyzerNodeFftSize":2048,"AnalyzerNodeFrequencyBinCount":1024,"AnalyzerNodeMinDecibels":-100,"AnalyzerNodeMaxDecibels":-30,"AnalyzerNodeSmoothingTimeConstant":0.8,"BiquadFilterNodeFrequencyDefaultValue":350,"BiquadFilterNodeFrequencyMaxValue":24000,"BiquadFilterNodeFrequencyMinValue":0,"BiquadFilterNodeDetuneDefaultValue":0,"BiquadFilterNodeDetuneMaxValue":153600,"BiquadFilterNodeDetuneMinValue":-153600,"BiquadFilterNodeQDefaultValue":1,"BiquadFilterNodeQMaxValue":3.4028234663852886e+38,"BiquadFilterNodeQMinValue":-3.4028234663852886e+38,"BiquadFilterNodeGainDefaultValue":0,"BiquadFilterNodeGainMaxValue":1541.273681640625,"BiquadFilterNodeGainMinValue":-3.4028234663852886e+38,"BiquadFilterNodeType":"lowpass","AudioBufferSourceNodeDetuneDefaultValue":0,"AudioBufferSourceNodeDetuneMaxValue":3.4028234663852886e+38,"AudioBufferSourceNodeDetuneMinValue":-3.4028234663852886e+38,"AudioBufferSourceNodePlaybackRateDefaultValue":1,"AudioBufferSourceNodePlaybackRateMaxValue":3.4028234663852886e+38,"AudioBufferSourceNodePlaybackRateMinValue":-3.4028234663852886e+38,"ConstantSourceNodeOffsetDefaultValue":1,"ConstantSourceNodeOffsetMaxValue":3.4028234663852886e+38,"ConstantSourceNodeOffsetMinValue":-3.4028234663852886e+38,"DelayNodeDelayTimeDefaultValue":0,"DelayNodeDelayTimeMaxValue":1,"DelayNodeDelayTimeMinValue":0,"DynamicsCompressorNodeThresholdDefaultValue":-24,"DynamicsCompressorNodeThresholdMaxValue":0,"DynamicsCompressorNodeThresholdMinValue":-100,"DynamicsCompressorNodeKneeDefaultValue":30,"DynamicsCompressorNodeKneeMaxValue":40,"DynamicsCompressorNodeKneeMinValue":0,"DynamicsCompressorNodeRatioDefaultValue":12,"DynamicsCompressorNodeRatioMaxValue":20,"DynamicsCompressorNodeRatioMinValue":1,"DynamicsCompressorNodeReduction":0,"DynamicsCompressorNodeAttackDefaultValue":0.003000000026077032,"DynamicsCompressorNodeAttackMaxValue":1,"DynamicsCompressorNodeAttackMinValue":0,"DynamicsCompressorNodeReleaseDefaultValue":0.25,"DynamicsCompressorNodeReleaseMaxValue":1,"DynamicsCompressorNodeReleaseMinValue":0,"GainNodeGainDefaultValue":1,"GainNodeGainMaxValue":3.4028234663852886e+38,"GainNodeGainMinValue":-3.4028234663852886e+38,"OscillatorNodeFrequencyDefaultValue":440,"OscillatorNodeFrequencyMaxValue":24000,"OscillatorNodeFrequencyMinValue":-24000,"OscillatorNodeDetuneDefaultValue":0,"OscillatorNodeDetuneMaxValue":153600,"OscillatorNodeDetuneMinValue":-153600,"OscillatorNodeType":"sine","StereoPannerNodePanDefaultValue":0,"StereoPannerNodePanMaxValue":1,"StereoPannerNodePanMinValue":-1,"AudioListenerPositionXDefaultValue":0,"AudioListenerPositionXMaxValue":3.4028234663852886e+38,"AudioListenerPositionXMinValue":-3.4028234663852886e+38,"AudioListenerPositionYDefaultValue":0,"AudioListenerPositionYMaxValue":3.4028234663852886e+38,"AudioListenerPositionYMinValue":-3.4028234663852886e+38,"AudioListenerPositionZDefaultValue":0,"AudioListenerPositionZMaxValue":3.4028234663852886e+38,"AudioListenerPositionZMinValue":-3.4028234663852886e+38,"AudioListenerForwardXDefaultValue":0,"AudioListenerForwardXMaxValue":3.4028234663852886e+38,"AudioListenerForwardXMinValue":-3.4028234663852886e+38,"AudioListenerForwardYDefaultValue":0,"AudioListenerForwardYMaxValue":3.4028234663852886e+38,"AudioListenerForwardYMinValue":-3.4028234663852886e+38,"AudioListenerForwardZDefaultValue":-1,"AudioListenerForwardZMaxValue":3.4028234663852886e+38,"AudioListenerForwardZMinValue":-3.4028234663852886e+38,"AudioListenerUpXDefaultValue":0,"AudioListenerUpXMaxValue":3.4028234663852886e+38,"AudioListenerUpXMinValue":-3.4028234663852886e+38,"AudioListenerUpYDefaultValue":1,"AudioListenerUpYMaxValue":3.4028234663852886e+38,"AudioListenerUpYMinValue":-3.4028234663852886e+38,"AudioListenerUpZDefaultValue":0,"AudioListenerUpZMaxValue":3.4028234663852886e+38,"AudioListenerUpZMinValue":-3.4028234663852886e+38,"PannerNodePositionXDefaultValue":0,"PannerNodePositionXMaxValue":3.4028234663852886e+38,"PannerNodePositionXMinValue":-3.4028234663852886e+38,"PannerNodePositionYDefaultValue":0,"PannerNodePositionYMaxValue":3.4028234663852886e+38,"PannerNodePositionYMinValue":-3.4028234663852886e+38,"PannerNodePositionZDefaultValue":0,"PannerNodePositionZMaxValue":3.4028234663852886e+38,"PannerNodePositionZMinValue":-3.4028234663852886e+38,"PannerNodeOrientationXDefaultValue":1,"PannerNodeOrientationXMaxValue":3.4028234663852886e+38,"PannerNodeOrientationXMinValue":-3.4028234663852886e+38,"PannerNodeOrientationYDefaultValue":0,"PannerNodeOrientationYMaxValue":3.4028234663852886e+38,"PannerNodeOrientationYMinValue":-3.4028234663852886e+38,"PannerNodeOrientationZDefaultValue":0,"PannerNodeOrientationZMaxValue":3.4028234663852886e+38,"PannerNodeOrientationZMinValue":-3.4028234663852886e+38},"fonts":["Arial","Arial Black","Calibri","Cambria","Cambria Math","Comic Sans MS","Consolas","Courier New","Georgia","Impact","Lucida Console","Lucida Sans Unicode","Microsoft Sans Serif","MS Gothic","MS PGothic","Palatino Linotype","Segoe Print","Segoe Script","Segoe UI","Segoe UI Light","Segoe UI Semibold","Segoe UI Symbol","Tahoma","Times New Roman","Trebuchet MS","Verdana","Wingdings","Candara","Constantia","Corbel","Ebrima","Gabriola","Malgun Gothic","Marlett","Microsoft Himalaya","Microsoft JhengHei","Microsoft New Tai Lue","Microsoft PhagsPa","Microsoft Tai Le","Microsoft YaHei","Microsoft Yi Baiti","MingLiU_HKSCS-ExtB","MingLiU-ExtB","Mongolian Baiti","MS UI Gothic","MV Boli","NSimSun","PMingLiU-ExtB","SimSun","SimSun-ExtB","Sylfaen","Cambria Italic","Corbel Bold Italic","Cambria Bold Italic","Tahoma Negreta","Sitka Banner","Cambria Bold","Trebuchet MS Bold Italic","Microsoft JhengHei Light","Candara Italic","Georgia Bold","Verdana Italic","Javanese Text","Palatino Linotype Bold","Segoe UI Emoji","Leelawadee UI","Yu Gothic UI Light","Verdana Bold Italic","Constantia Bold","Sitka Small","Times New Roman Bold Italic","Franklin Gothic Medium","Sitka Text","Nirmala UI","Calibri Italic","Corbel Bold","Myanmar Text","Franklin Gothic Medium Italic","Segoe UI Semilight","Arial Italic","Sitka Display","Consolas Bold Italic","Sitka Heading","Trebuchet MS Bold","Times New Roman Bold","Segoe UI Historic","Microsoft YaHei UI Light","Malgun Gothic Semilight","Microsoft YaHei UI","Corbel Italic","Microsoft JhengHei UI","Times New Roman Italic","Yu Gothic UI Semilight","Segoe MDL2 Assets","Microsoft YaHei Light","Courier New Bold","Arial Bold","Georgia Bold Italic","Yu Gothic Light","Webdings","Comic Sans MS Bold","Nirmala UI Semilight","Consolas Italic","Yu Gothic Medium","Trebuchet MS Italic","Consolas Bold","Candara Bold Italic","Courier New Bold Italic","Constantia Bold Italic","Microsoft JhengHei UI Light","Arial Bold Italic","Gadugi","Calibri Light","Verdana Bold","Microsoft Tai Le Bold","Constantia Italic","Sitka Subheading","Symbol","Leelawadee UI Semilight","Palatino Linotype Bold Italic","Segoe UI Black","Georgia Italic","Courier New Italic","Candara Bold","Palatino Linotype Italic","Yu Gothic UI Semibold","Calibri Bold Italic","Calibri Bold","Bahnschrift","Bahnschrift Light","Bahnschrift SemiBold","Bahnschrift SemiLight","Calibri Light Italic","Candara Light","Candara Light Italic","Comic Sans MS Bold Italic","Comic Sans MS Italic","Corbel Light","Corbel Light Italic","Ebrima Bold","Gadugi Bold","HoloLens MDL2 Assets","Ink Free","Leelawadee UI Bold","Malgun Gothic Bold","Microsoft JhengHei Bold","Microsoft JhengHei UI Bold","Microsoft New Tai Lue Bold","Microsoft PhagsPa Bold","Microsoft YaHei Bold","Microsoft YaHei UI Bold","Myanmar Text Bold","Nirmala UI Bold","Segoe Print Bold","Segoe Script Bold","Segoe UI Black Italic","Segoe UI Bold","Segoe UI Bold Italic","Segoe UI Italic","Segoe UI Light Italic","Segoe UI Semibold Italic","Segoe UI Semilight Italic","Sitka Banner Bold","Sitka Banner Bold Italic","Sitka Banner Italic","Sitka Display Bold","Sitka Display Bold Italic","Sitka Display Italic","Sitka Heading Bold","Sitka Heading Bold Italic","Sitka Heading Italic","Sitka Small Bold","Sitka Small Bold Italic","Sitka Small Italic","Sitka Subheading Bold","Sitka Subheading Bold Italic","Sitka Subheading Italic","Sitka Text Bold","Sitka Text Bold Italic","Sitka Text Italic","Tahoma Bold","Yu Gothic Bold","Yu Gothic Regular","Yu Gothic UI Bold","Yu Gothic UI Regular","宋体","微软雅黑","ＭＳ ゴシック","ＭＳ Ｐゴシック","Arial Narrow","Courier","MS Sans Serif","MS Serif","Times","Yu Gothic UI","FontAwesome","Franklin Gothic Heavy","Yu Gothic","Franklin Gothic","Microsoft JhengHei Regular","Microsoft JhengHei UI Regular"],"headers":["Host","X-Real-Ip","X-Forwarded-For","Connection","Content-Length","Cache-Control","Sec-Ch-Ua","Accept-Datetime","X-Csrf-Token","If-Unmodified-Since","Authorization","X-Requested-With","If-Modified-Since","If-Range","X-Http-Method-Override","X-Request-Id","Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform","Pragma","Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile","User-Agent","Content-Type","Max-Forwards","Upgrade-Insecure-Requests","If-None-Match","If-Match","Range","Accept","Origin","Sec-Fetch-Site","Sec-Fetch-Mode","Sec-Fetch-Dest","Referer","Accept-Encoding","Accept-Language"],"lang":"en-US,en;q=0.9","native_code":"function Object() { [native code] }","css":{"any-hover":"hover","any-pointer":"fine","aspect-ratio":20734,"color":8,"color-gamut":"srgb","color-index":0,"device-aspect-ratio":17777,"device-height":900,"device-width":1600,"grid":"0","height":749,"width":1553,"hover":"hover","monochrome":0,"orientation":"landscape","pointer":"fine","prefers-color-scheme":"dark","prefers-contrast":"no-preference","prefers-reduced-motion":"no-preference","resolution":96},"media":{"devices":[{"deviceId":"","kind":"audioinput","label":"","groupId":"ee980e6b38eb2b96c7ae347f510e013d83aa4e3d9dc63e3e8b51e12539c7cfd1"},{"deviceId":"","kind":"videoinput","label":"","groupId":"39afe388bab8dc331b697c1304b8d754ebb6ccf3f3280b711177946ae5c983af"},{"deviceId":"","kind":"audiooutput","label":"","groupId":"24cac178aef8eb210fc685c6479c9bea8cb89bf493524a6feaa8f2a593c7edcd"}],"constraints":{"aspectRatio":true,"autoGainControl":true,"brightness":true,"channelCount":true,"colorTemperature":true,"contrast":true,"deviceId":true,"echoCancellation":true,"exposureCompensation":true,"exposureMode":true,"exposureTime":true,"facingMode":true,"focusDistance":true,"focusMode":true,"frameRate":true,"groupId":true,"height":true,"iso":true,"latency":true,"noiseSuppression":true,"pan":true,"pointsOfInterest":true,"resizeMode":true,"sampleRate":true,"sampleSize":true,"saturation":true,"sharpness":true,"tilt":true,"torch":true,"whiteBalanceMode":true,"width":true,"zoom":true}},"speech":[{"name":"Microsoft David - English (United States)","lang":"en-US","localService":true,"voiceURI":"Microsoft David - English (United States)","default":true},{"name":"Microsoft Mark - English (United States)","lang":"en-US","localService":true,"voiceURI":"Microsoft Mark - English (United States)","default":false},{"name":"Microsoft Zira - English (United States)","lang":"en-US","localService":true,"voiceURI":"Microsoft Zira - English (United States)","default":false},{"name":"Microsoft Adri Online (Natural) - Afrikaans (South Africa)","lang":"af-ZA","localService":false,"voiceURI":"Microsoft Adri Online (Natural) - Afrikaans (South Africa)","default":false},{"name":"Microsoft Mekdes Online (Natural) - Amharic (Ethiopia)","lang":"am-ET","localService":false,"voiceURI":"Microsoft Mekdes Online (Natural) - Amharic (Ethiopia)","default":false},{"name":"Microsoft Salma Online (Natural) - Arabic (Egypt)","lang":"ar-EG","localService":false,"voiceURI":"Microsoft Salma Online (Natural) - Arabic (Egypt)","default":false},{"name":"Microsoft Zariyah Online (Natural) - Arabic (Saudi Arabia)","lang":"ar-SA","localService":false,"voiceURI":"Microsoft Zariyah Online (Natural) - Arabic (Saudi Arabia)","default":false},{"name":"Microsoft Nabanita Online (Natural) - Bangla (Bangladesh)","lang":"bn-BD","localService":false,"voiceURI":"Microsoft Nabanita Online (Natural) - Bangla (Bangladesh)","default":false},{"name":"Microsoft Tanishaa Online (Natural) - Bengali (India)","lang":"bn-IN","localService":false,"voiceURI":"Microsoft Tanishaa Online (Natural) - Bengali (India)","default":false},{"name":"Microsoft Kalina Online (Natural) - Bulgarian (Bulgaria)","lang":"bg-BG","localService":false,"voiceURI":"Microsoft Kalina Online (Natural) - Bulgarian (Bulgaria)","default":false},{"name":"Microsoft Nilar Online (Natural) - Burmese (Myanmar)","lang":"my-MM","localService":false,"voiceURI":"Microsoft Nilar Online (Natural) - Burmese (Myanmar)","default":false},{"name":"Microsoft Joana Online (Natural) - Catalan (Spain)","lang":"ca-ES","localService":false,"voiceURI":"Microsoft Joana Online (Natural) - Catalan (Spain)","default":false},{"name":"Microsoft HiuMaan Online (Natural) - Chinese (Hong Kong)","lang":"zh-HK","localService":false,"voiceURI":"Microsoft HiuMaan Online (Natural) - Chinese (Hong Kong)","default":false},{"name":"Microsoft Xiaoxiao Online (Natural) - Chinese (Mainland)","lang":"zh-CN","localService":false,"voiceURI":"Microsoft Xiaoxiao Online (Natural) - Chinese (Mainland)","default":false},{"name":"Microsoft Yunyang Online (Natural) - Chinese (Mainland)","lang":"zh-CN","localService":false,"voiceURI":"Microsoft Yunyang Online (Natural) - Chinese (Mainland)","default":false},{"name":"Microsoft HsiaoChen Online (Natural) - Chinese (Taiwan)","lang":"zh-TW","localService":false,"voiceURI":"Microsoft HsiaoChen Online (Natural) - Chinese (Taiwan)","default":false},{"name":"Microsoft Gabrijela Online (Natural) - Croatian (Croatia)","lang":"hr-HR","localService":false,"voiceURI":"Microsoft Gabrijela Online (Natural) - Croatian (Croatia)","default":false},{"name":"Microsoft Vlasta Online (Natural) - Czech (Czech)","lang":"cs-CZ","localService":false,"voiceURI":"Microsoft Vlasta Online (Natural) - Czech (Czech)","default":false},{"name":"Microsoft Christel Online (Natural) - Danish (Denmark)","lang":"da-DK","localService":false,"voiceURI":"Microsoft Christel Online (Natural) - Danish (Denmark)","default":false},{"name":"Microsoft Dena Online (Natural) - Dutch (Belgium)","lang":"nl-BE","localService":false,"voiceURI":"Microsoft Dena Online (Natural)...
```

I have no idea how to use it on selenium. Can you help me?

Comment: How you want to use Json file with Selenium?

Comment: I don't know that's why I'm asking)

Comment: So, your question is very unclear. At least for me.

Comment: So my qestion is that how to use fingerprint data from json file in selenium

Comment: As a human user, how do you use Json data when clicking on elements or reading texts on some web page?

Comment: OMG do understand what is fingerprint?